# Mysql: How can I retrieve rows 2 months after they where created_at

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to retrieve userdata where the user was created 2 months ago

**BUT** I'm not interested in retrieving users who where created yesterday,  2 days ago, 1 months ago and so on. (Those users I will be in two months depending on their created_at date). I hope it makes sense.

The only thing I was able to find information about is getting data from now and 2 months ago. But that's not what I want.

```
SELECT 
s.id, 
s.user_id, 
u.name
FROM 
    subscriptions s
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
WHERE 
    s.status = 1
AND
  DATE(u.created_at) >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
AND
    s.subscription_id = 1 
AND 
    u.is_active  = 1
```

Comment: As stated, the requirements will cause a row to start appearing after mos, and CONTINUE to appear every day thereafter.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Can you confirm this is what you want? 1. Get users that was created prior to 2 months ago. 2. Get the data from those users from then until now.

Comment: It should be exactly the datetime created 2 months ago for that specific user. So if I create an user 2 months ago and you create it 2 months ago as well but one hour later I should be the first to get the email and you 1 hour later. Which the cronjob will manage based on the sql im trying to solve. Does it makes any sense?:)

Comment: @wiliam . . . "2 months" is indeterminate.  You need to be more explicit.  That is why sample data and desired results help.  For instance, what is "2 months" after Dec 30?

Comment: It has a datetime. So it will depend on the time the users are created.

Comment: If it's time specific, you can't use `DATE()`. That will trim the datetime value to only DATE. Then if it's hour specific, try using `DATE_FORMAT(u.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00')=DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH,'%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00')`

Comment: beautiful. can u post as an answer. so I can accept:)

Comment: @tcadidot0 check my message above.

Comment: Sorry, I was at home already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comment, try to use `DATE_FORMAT` to get the date+hour combo:

```
SELECT 
s.id, 
s.user_id, 
u.name
FROM 
    subscriptions s
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
WHERE 
    s.status = 1
AND
   DATE_FORMAT(u.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH,'%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00')
AND
    s.subscription_id = 1 
AND 
    u.is_active  = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATEDIFF()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp)function
and compare day

```
SELECT 
s.id, 
s.user_id, 
u.name
FROM 
    subscriptions s
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
WHERE 
    s.status = 1
AND
  DATEDIFF(created_date,NOW())>=60
AND
    s.subscription_id = 1 
AND 
    u.is_active  = 1
```